# Fetch conditional rows in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query like below. ApplicationID and InvoiceNumber columns show purchases made. Negative values in the Revenue rows indicate shopping refund. The ApplicationID column does not change when the purchase is refunded, but the InvoiceNumber column changes for the refund. I determine the returns according to the price totals of different InvoiceNumbers in the same ApplicationID equal to zero. For example, customer A bought  4 products that InvoiceNumber=AA in ApplicationID=11 shopping, but refund 2 of them (InvoiceNumber=BB). I want to get the remaining rows after the refunds are extracted. So in this example, rows 1-2 and 5-6 will eliminate each other for ApplicationID=11 and only rows 3-4  will remain. In addition, ApplicationID=22 and ApplicationID=33 rows will also come as it does not contain refunds. Finally, rows 3,4,7, 8 and 9 will get. How do I do this?

```
CustomerCode    ApplicationID   InvoiceNumber   Date    Revenue
A                     11              AA      1.01.2020   150
A                     11              AA      2.01.2020   200
A                     11              AA      1.01.2020   250
A                     11              AA      1.01.2020   300
A                     11              BB      5.01.2020  -150
A                     11              BB      5.01.2020  -200
A                     22              CC      7.02.2020   500
A                     22              DD      7.02.2020   700
A                     11              AA      2.01.2020   800
```

I wrote the result I want. I want to subtract zero sum of revenue according to CustomerCode and ApplicationID and fetch all other columns

example code:

```
      select a.CustomerCode,a.ApplicationID from Table a
      group by CustomerCode,a.ApplicationID             
  having SUM(Revenue)>0
```

My desired result:

```
CustomerCode    ApplicationID   InvoiceNumber   Date    Revenue
A                     11              AA      1.01.2020   250
A                     11              AA      1.01.2020   300
A                     22              CC      7.02.2020   500
A                     22              DD      7.02.2020   700
A                     11              AA      2.01.2020   800
```

Comment: how do you identify the products returned is the first two? Not the third and forth? Based on its price?

Comment: Please provide DDL + DML commands

Comment: I determine the returns according to the price totals of different InvoiceNumbers in the same ApplicationID equal to zero.

Comment: what do you mean by in the same Application ID equal to zero

Comment: so the same ApplicationID means the same shopping. InvoiceNumber is different because ApplicationID=11 has return. ie line 1-2 and line 5-6 shopping records belonging to applicationID=11 shopping. return record of row 1 is row 5  (because the same revenues only one of them negative). return record of row 2 is row 6

Comment: Its really not clear what you are asking. Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good. I could not explain my request. I added a sample code above. I want to subtract zero sum of revenue according to CustomerCode and ApplicationID and fetch all other columns. I added "having SUM(Revenue)>0" to extract returns

Comment: But we also need **BOTH** sample data **AND** your desired results - you are only showing one of those - and I'm not sure which.

Comment: so for those refund transaction will also be in the same table? or separate table? @BugraVarol

Comment: I showed the result I desired above. row 1,2,5 and 6 will not be because sum of 1,2,5 and 6 equal to zero

Comment: Those who have a refund will be completely removed. above I showed the output for this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've gone down a route of needing to sum your results to remove certain rows from your data but that's not necessarily the case.

You can use a LEFT JOIN back to itself joining on `CustomerCode`, `ApplicationID` and `Revenue = -Revenue`; this effectively finds "purchase" rows that have an associated "refund" row (and vice versa). You can then just filter them off with your WHERE clause

Here's the code I used

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Orders
CREATE TABLE #Orders (CustomerCode VARCHAR(1), ApplicationID INT, InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(2), [Date] DATE, Revenue INT)
INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerCode, ApplicationID, InvoiceNumber, Date, Revenue)
VALUES ('A', 11, 'AA', '2020-01-01', 150),
       ('A', 11, 'AA', '2020-01-02', 200),
       ('A', 11, 'AA', '2020-01-01', 250),
       ('A', 11, 'AA', '2020-01-01', 300),
       ('A', 11, 'BB', '2020-01-05', -150),
       ('A', 11, 'BB', '2020-01-05', -200),
       ('A', 22, 'CC', '2020-01-07', 500),
       ('A', 22, 'DD', '2020-01-07', 700),
       ('A', 11, 'AA', '2020-01-02', 800)

SELECT O.CustomerCode, O.ApplicationID, O.InvoiceNumber, O.Date, O.Revenue
FROM #Orders AS O
LEFT JOIN #Orders AS O2 ON O2.ApplicationID = O.ApplicationID AND O2.CustomerCode = O.CustomerCode AND O.Revenue = -O2.Revenue
WHERE O2.ApplicationID IS NULL
```

And this is the output:

```
CustomerCode    ApplicationID   InvoiceNumber   Date        Revenue 
A               11              AA              2020-01-01  250 
A               11              AA              2020-01-01  300 
A               22              CC              2020-01-07  500 
A               22              DD              2020-01-07  700 
A               11              AA              2020-01-02  800
```